# How to test a page with an autoplaying video in Chrome on WebPageTest?

Tags: performance-testing, autoplay, web-performance, webpagetest

I have a page I want to test in WebPageTest in Chrome, but it has an autoplaying video, and Chrome autoplay policy disallows autoplay by default.

How do I force-enable the autoplay in Chrome on WebPageTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command line options field, put `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`

[image: webpagetest autoplay]